# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code below to find numbers starting `34` and `54` but i am getting the error

> > 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE address LIKE '34%' at line 1, Time: 0.123000s

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.table
WHERE uid = 'test' 
  AND WHERE destination_addr LIKE '34%' 
  AND WHERE address LIKE '54%';
```

What could i be doing wrong ?

Comment: Just remove second and third `WHERE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many `WHERE` clause usage. Use only one `WHERE` like below-

```
SELECT * 
 FROM db.table
WHERE uid = 'test' 
AND destination_addr LIKE '34%' 
AND address LIKE '54%';
```

**See Syntax**: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html